# AWS AutoScaling: how to disable health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have a Rube Goldberg system where I launch spot-priced instances in autoscaling groups, without actually being interesting in autoscaling features. It all comes from not being able to get spot-priced instances directly using CloudFormation. Don't ask...

Anyway, for my use case, I want to effectively disable health checks. I never want instances terminated and replaced, ever. I will do all that manually. Because of health checks I am rather often seeing my carefully constructed instances being terminated, and it is very annoying.

So, what are my options?

1. Grace period set to maybe 0 or -1 as a way of saying *grace period forever*?
2. Grace period set to Integer.MAX_INT which is probably good enough?
3. `set-instance-health` which they advertise for custom health checks: does that override EC2 status checks? Is it permanent?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are using spot instances, they *will* get terminated (and possibly replaced, depending on price settings) eventually, unless your bid is absurdly high.  (Actually, no instance on EC2 is forever, but spot instances are by their bidding nature much more volatile.)  As for whether the autoscaling group will scale in, just set min == desired == max and leave it there.  However, again, if a spot instance is terminated by AWS (but not by the autoscaling group), the autoscaling group will try to replace it.

Comment: @KarenB Thanks, I already have the min/ max/ desired bit in place.

As for volatility, we accept that spot priced instances are volatile due to prices and bidding and all that. In our experience though that isn't much of a problem, and we get large savings from this. The health checks are much more intrusive.

Answer (score 5):

So, I asked AWS Support and the kind Dan H. told me about suspending processes, which is exactly what I need: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html - I can actually disable health checks directly.